# Replacing missing values in a dataset with a numeric?

Tags: r, missing-data

I've imported a spreadsheet of data into R using the `read.xlsx` command but there are elements marked `Low` interspersed in the data because they weren't measured properly.

So an example column in the data looks like this:

```
[15, 6, Low, 23, 39, Low]
```

I want to replace the `Low` elements with numeric values but when I try a command like:

`data[3,2] <- 4` #.....I get the following error message:

```
Warning message: 
In '[<-.factor '('*tmp*', iseq, value = 4): invalid factor level, NAs generated.
```

I've tried various combinations of `as.numeric`, `as.character`, `as.factor` but none of them get round this error message.

I've been told that the way to do this, is to convert the `Low` elements to missing values but when I do this and try to replace the NAs with a numeric, I still get the same error message!

Comment: Set `option(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` before importing your data. However, you will end up with a character variable, which you will need to coerce to numeric before doing any calculations. Also, set the `Low` values to `NA` (which denotes unknown values) and leave it like that. R comes with facilities to deal with `NA`. `read.table` (and other data import functions) comes with a `na.strings` parameter which allows coercing `Low` to `NA` during import.

Comment: [Cross posting](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/49964-R-how-best-to-replace-a-missing-value-in-a-dataset-with-a-numeric) without stating you're doing so is considered rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factor is a type of variable that only accepts predefined values. So if you have the following factor :

```
fac <- factor(c("15","6","Low","23","39","Low"))
```

Then the predefinded set of values is :

```
R> levels(fac)
[1] "15"  "23"  "39"  "6"   "Low"
```

If you want to attribute `"4"` as a velue, you either have to change your factor labels :

```
R> factor(fac, levels=c("15","23","39","6","Low"), labels=c("15","23","39","6","4"))
[1] 15 6  4  23 39 4
```

Or first convert it to a character vector :

```
R> v <- as.character(fac)
R> v[v=="Low"] <- "4"
R> v
[1] "15" "6"  "4"  "23" "39" "4"
```

Comment: That works great. Just 1 more query:

What do you do if the way the 'Low' is displayed in the data varies so you can't always pick it up with v=="Low"

Eg: data = [5 6 Low< 13 27 <Low 14 Low*]  

I tried:

v[grep("Low",v)] <- "4"  but that didn't work, returning this error message:

Warning message: 
In '[<-.factor '('*tmp*', iseq, value = 4): invalid factor level, NAs generated.

Comment: Did you use `as.character(v)` before your call to `grep` ?